# How toolchain is related to OS and platform architecture

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, arm, cpu-architecture

Can someone explain about toolchain dependency on OS and platform architecture, for instance if I want to compile code for an arm architecture, should I look for platform architecture or for OS that platform is running on and then adapt toolchain to it?

Comment: Question is not concrete enough.

Comment: What does *libc* or the standard 'C' library do?  How about [libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html)?  If you code without calling a standard library, then you need only have a *libgcc* (or equivalent) and the compiler is not related to the target OS.  Of course if the target OS has a loader, you need to get your executable into a format supported by that (maybe custom linker scripts).  For a simple binary format this part is easy.  For instance, the linux kernel may compile with 'arm-none-eabi-gcc' or 'arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc' because the code uses no OS functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most compilers compile their code to the assembly language. The code they produce will most likely depend on various calls to the operating system (e.g. to allocate dynamic memory), and have a header defining properties of the file like the location of the code and data sections (e.g. ELF, PE). An assembler then compiles this assembly to object files, which are linked using the linker of this platform. All these tools produce code for a specific architecture and OS.

This does not mean that the compiler and linker cannot run on another type of system. The process of compiling code for another system is called cross-compiling. Even though this is less commonly used than compiling for the same platform as the compiler runs on, it is quite commonly used. A few examples of this are compiling OS kernels, which of course cannot rely on another OS, or compiling native code for Android (the android NDK contains a cross-compiler).